# Newbie can't get concurrent.futures to work at all

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get started with concurrent.futures, and my first little toy example fails.  I'm running python 3.8.5 on Mac OS 10.14.6 (Mojave).

Here's my script

```
 from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor 

def foo(x):
    return 2*x

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    xs = [1,2]
    results = executor.map(foo, xs)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

I didn't originally have `max_workers=2` but I added it after the script failed, to no avail.

The script produces a raft of error messages that don't make much sense to me, in particular the references to `freeze_support` which the docs seem to say has application only on Windows machines.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/saul/Desktop/junk.py", line 8, in <module>
    results = executor.map(foo, xs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 674, in map
    results = super().map(partial(_process_chunk, fn),
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 600, in map
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 600, in <listcomp>
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 645, in submit
    self._start_queue_management_thread()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 584, in _start_queue_management_thread
    self._adjust_process_count()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 608, in _adjust_process_count
    p.start()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 42, in _launch
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/saul/Desktop/junk.py", line 8, in <module>
    results = executor.map(foo, xs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 674, in map
    results = super().map(partial(_process_chunk, fn),
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 600, in map
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 600, in <listcomp>
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 645, in submit
    self._start_queue_management_thread()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 584, in _start_queue_management_thread
    self._adjust_process_count()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 608, in _adjust_process_count
    p.start()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 42, in _launch
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "junk.py", line 9, in <module>
    for result in results:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something that simply doesn't work on the Mac?

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you try doing what it suggests?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried adding `freeze_support` if that's what you're asking, but that's from the multiprocessing module, not concurrent.futures, and I as I said, the docs says it only applies to Windows machines.

Comment: No, it explicitly tells you you don't need to add that, I'm talking about the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. Note, `ProcessPoolExecutor` *uses* `multiprocessing`

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that's what it meant.  Thanks.

Comment: Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) at the "Safe importing of main module" section. Mac OS now uses forkserver by default.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks again.